# Getting a sub-collection of a model in a template with Underscore and Backbone

Tags: templates, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I have a JSon like this that is a collection of issues:

```
{
            "id": "505",
            "issuedate": "2013-01-15 06:00:00",
            "lastissueupdate": "2013-01-15 13:51:08",
            "epub": false,
            "pdf": true,
            "price": 3,
            "description": "Diese Version ist nur als PDF verfügbar.",
            "downloadable": true,
            "renderings": [
                {
                    "height": 976,
                    "width": 1024,
                    "sourcetype": "pdf",
                    "pagenr": 0,
                    "purpose": "newsstand",
                    "relativePath": null,
                    "size": 0,
                    "url": "a/url/image.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "height": 488,
                    "width": 512,
                    "sourcetype": "pdf",
                    "pagenr": 0,
                    "purpose": "newsstand",
                    "relativePath": null,
                    "size": 0,
                    "url": "a/url/image.jpg"
                }
}
```

I'm using backbone and I want to access the sub-elements (renderings).
I overwrite the parse method to tell that my 'renderings' is a new collection, this part works fine.
Where I'm getting some problems is when i pass my collection of issues in my template. Then I can make a for each on the issues and accessing his attributes (id, issuedate, lastissueupdate,etc) but how can I access the renderings of my issues ?

My View:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html',
  'collections/issues/IssueCollection'
], function($, _, Backbone, homeTemplate, IssueCollection){

  var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),

    initialize:function(){
      var that = this;


      var onDataHandler = function(issues){
        that.render();


      }
      this.issues = new IssueCollection();
      this.issues.fetch({
        success:onDataHandler, 
        error:function(){
          alert("nicht gut")
        }
      });
    },

    render: function(){

      $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
      $('.menu li a[href="#"]').parent().addClass('active');
      var compiledTemplate = _.template(homeTemplate, {_:_, issues: this.issues.models});
      this.$el.html(compiledTemplate);

    }

  });

  return HomeView;

});
```

Then I have a very basic template.

To resume, I have a collection ISSUES of models ISSUE containing a collection of RENDERINGS and I want to access the model RENDER in my template.

edit:
**IssueCollection**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/issue/IssueModel'
], function(_, Backbone, IssueModel){

    var IssueCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: IssueModel,

        url: function(){
            return '/padpaper-ws/v1/pp/fn/issues';
        },

        parse: function(response){
            return response.issues;
        }

        //initialize : function(models, options) {},

    });
    return IssueCollection;
});
```

**IssueModel**

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'collections/renderings/RenderingsCollection'
], function(_, Backbone, RenderingsCollection) {

  var IssueModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response){
      response.renderings = new RenderingsCollection(response.renderings);
      return response;
     },
    set: function(attributes, options) {
      if (attributes.renderings !== undefined && !(attributes.renderings instanceof RenderingsCollection)) {
        attributes.renderings = new RenderingsCollection(attributes.renderings);
      }
      return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);
    }
  });
  return IssueModel;
});
```

**RenderingsCollection**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/rendering/RenderingModel'
], function(_, Backbone, RenderingModel){

    var RenderingsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: RenderingModel

        //initialize : function(models, options) {},

    });
    return RenderingsCollection;
});
```

**RenderingModel**

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

  var RenderingModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  return RenderingModel;

});
```

Thank's !!

Comment: I can't see the model RENDER, it that the parent object of _renderings_?

Comment: *I have a JSon like this that is a collection of issues:* I'd say it's just an `issue`, not a collection.

Comment: @Loamhoof, this is just the first one, there are a lot of other ones.

Comment: @akoskm, basically i have in my IssueModel the parse method that put a collection of renderings in my 'renderings'. I will update the code.

Comment: @brunettia I guess so, still it's confusing, that could well have been the whole collection, which didn't make much sense. Wrap it with [].

Comment: @Loamhoof It starts like this "issues": [ but I didn't put it in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I could use a double _.each in my template like this, giving my models from the view.

```
<% _.each(issues, function(issue) { %>
    .... code ...
    <% _.each(issue.get('renderings'), function(rendering) { %>
```

And then to access my renderings attributes we do like this:

```
<%= rendering.url %>
```

for example, not "get" like the first time.

Thank's for your participation!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Collection#toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) method to have a complete representation of your whole data. Still, you'd have to use `model.attributes.key` to access the attributes of your models. So I'd not so much recommend it. Instead, I'd say you should build your own JSON object (using the toJSON method recursively). (I'll update with some code if it's not clear)

**Edit:**

```
var data = [], renderings;
for(var i=0; i<issues.length; i++) {
  data.push(issues.models[i].toJSON());
  data[i].renderings = [];
  renderings = issues.models[i].get('renderings');
  for(var j=0; j<renderings.length; j++) {
    data[i].renderings.push(renderings.models[j].toJSON());
  }
}
```

for example would give you the whole data, and you could access any attribute easily.

Comment: I don't see exactly how this can save me :) (I'm very new...) if you could put a little example to access every renderings that would be very nice!

Comment: Basically, this piece of code would give you the whole JSON representation of your ISSUES, without Backbone's internal stuff. So... more or less the JSON object you showed in your question. Just test it and `console.log(data);`. You'll see what it looks like.